# In Function, How to return more than one values without using ref cursor?

Tags: function, plsql, ref-cursor

In Function How to return more than one values without using ref cursor?

Comment: You can return out parameters with a function but, in general, that's a terrible idea. Why do you want to do this, and why can't you use a procedure instead?

Comment: You can return a record type, object type or table type. For the latter you can make a piped function. You can use out parameters as well. But it's impossible to suggest the best solution, since your question lacks relevant details about what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

Mostly, you dont.

You make a procedure